# How to use a variable as a type when declaring a generic object in Java

Tags: java, generics

Although it's hard for me to explain the problem with the right terminology, I will try my best to demonstrate.

I want to make a method that generates a new `TableView` with the following parameters:

```
private TableView<T extends MySuperClass> createTable(T subClass, String[] names, String[] varNames)
```

When Im creating the `TableColumn`s, I need to know the types of each column. I thought maybe that by accessing each of the `names` get-methods, i could use `Type type = getMethod(methodName).getAnnotatedReturnType().getType()` to get the return type and then use this as a type, and then use it as followed:

```
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
   TableColumn<T,type> tableColumn1 = new TableColumn<>(names[i]);
}
```

but that did not work.

So is there a way to use a Type object as the Type in a generic object?

**EDIT**

Im adding another example to clearify the question

```
Type type = ... //<---- What to put here?
ArrayList<type> someList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Is it posible to do something like this? If so, is `Type` the right Class/Interface to use?

Comment: Can you provide an example, because it is not clear to me what "type" your expect/want to get.

Comment: The variable 'type' could hold a String, Integer etc. @Tom

Comment: And how is your `createTable` supposed to understand that? I have no idea what you meant with `Type type = getMethod(methodName).getAnnotatedReturnType().getType()`. It is clear that you didn't know how to achieve what you wanted, that's fine, but what was your general approach there? And wouldn't be an additional parameter with the column type be the easiest solution here? You already have `T`, so you can also create a second generic variable, like "c", then use `Class<c> columnType` and then `TableColumn<T, C>`

Comment: @Tom methodName is just the name of the getMethod, e.g. "getName". Then by using that 'Method' I could use the 'getAnnotatedReturnType()' to get the return type (e.g. String). That was my aproach, but as I said, that didnt work. It was just an attempt. Im sorry if my question is a bit unclear. But thank you for that suggestion with the Class<c>, I will try that instead.

Comment: @Tom I added another example to clearify, hopefully its easier to understand what I want to achieve.

Comment: Well, after the edit I really think you should try the approach in my second comment, that will do what you want there. Regarding `Type type = ....` and `ArrayList<type>` that doesn't work, because the value in `<..>` must be a class, not a variable. But using Generics solves that issue for you.

Comment: Btw when you tried my approach and found it working for you, then feel free to post an answer with your working solution so future readers can learn from that as well.

Comment: @Tom OK thank you. I will do that!

Comment: Oh @Tom, I dont think this would work in this case because C would just be one class. I want to make several TableColumns and some of them may have different Classes. E.g. TableView<T,String> = new TableView<>(); and the next column could be something like: TableView<T,Integer> = new TableView<>();

Comment: In that case you can re-think your code structure. `createTable` should not be responsible to creating both the table and columns. You can create a dedicated method to create create a single `TableView` with the matching generics and then pass the collection of columns to `createTable`.